# How to list posts by term (custom taxonomy)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, terms

I created a custom post type **(portfolio)**, with custom taxonomy **(portfolio-category)**.
I created a template, this template lists all "portfolio" posts.

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
        <div class="portfolio-arrows" id="p-arrow-left" data-scroll-by="-300"></div>
        <div class="portfolio-arrows" id="p-arrow-right" data-scroll-by="300"></div>
        <div class="inner">
            <ul id="portfolio-container">
                <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                <li  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="portfolio-content">
                        <h2 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <span class="portfolio-date"><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <div class="featured-p-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-size' ); ?>
                        <div class="featured-p-image-hover">
                        <?php
                            $fullimage_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" );
                            echo'<a href="'.$fullimage_src[0].'" class="fancybox"></a>';  
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile;  ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

As you can see `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` in this page template the user can add content above the wp_query.

I created a file, taxonomy-portfolio-category.php with same content. With this I would like to list posts by term, but I would like to show the "user managed" content above the query too. *(The result is: I get same page, but instead of the unique content (user managed) I see the list by the term.)*

How can I do that? Or what's the best way for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the term description with `echo term_description()` or create a new custom post type for these descriptions and associate each post in that post type with one or more terms.

The term description is probably faster, but the custom post type can be searched, and you can add metaboxes and everything else like in other posts.

Comment: Maybe is misunderstanding, but I would like to show the original page's content on the term page. Btw term desc not good for me, because the user add the content when he/she create the page with my template.

It sounds strange.. maybe it's impossible.

Comment: I thought you are talking about the taxonomy archive. Why don't you use that?

Comment: What is taxonomy archive, taxonomy-portfolio-category.php this? I don't know what to use if I would like to show the original title and content (what I created as page), under that the filtered list.

Comment: @robert Each taxonomy gets its own archive and its own [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) if you want it. Happens automatically.

Comment: Oh, yes i understand. What do you think about my idea to show the original page template's content on every related page is it possible, or you think better to remove this idea?

Comment: @robert I think it is good to give each archive a little descriptive text. It shouldn't be too long (exception: author archives).